# Summing the first N primes

Tags: c++, sum

I need to create a program that takes 'N' as Input and show the first N prime numbers and finally sum them...
Here's my code, but it doesn't work. (It loops at: "if ((num == 2) || (num == 3))")

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

I can't use functions and arrays.

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int n, num = 1, rest, cont = 0, sum = 0;
    bool exit = false;
    int e = 1;

    cout<<"How many prime number do you want to show? ";
    cin>>n;

    while (cont <= n)
    {
        num++;
        if ((num == 2) || (num == 3))
        {
            cout<<num<<endl;
            sum += num;
            cont++;
        }
        else if (num%2 == 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            bool exit = false;
            int div = 3;
            while (!exit)
            {
                rest = num%div;

                if (num == div)
                {
                    exit = true;
                    cout<<num<<endl;
                    sum += num;
                    cont++;
                }

                if (rest == 0)
                    exit = true;                    
                div++;
            }
        }       
        num++;
    }    
    cout<<"Sum: "<<sum<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I can't use functions." - then what that `_tmain()` symbol is doing there?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not informative. Rather useless for any user who is willing to help you.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a question. Please refine your question to get a good answer.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you gave? Does it compile? If not, what error do you get? If it does, what happens when you run it? Please provide more details so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, you are using a variable name `resto` instead of `rest`, which is the name with which you declared it (`if (resto == 0)`).

Second, you increase `num` twice: at the beginning and at the end of your loop. Remove the last `num++` and it should work better.

Third, initialize `cont` to 1 and not to 0, or it will compute sum of the first N+1 primes instead of the first N primes.

Here is the fixed version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, num = 1, rest, cont = 1, sum = 0;
    bool exit = false;
    int e = 1;

    cout<<"How many prime number do you want to show? ";
    cin>>n;

    while (cont <= n)
    {
        num++;
        if ((num == 2) || (num == 3))
        {
            cout<<num<<endl;
            sum += num;
            cont++;
        }
        else if (num%2 == 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            bool exit = false;
            int div = 3;
            while (!exit)
            {
                rest = num%div;

                if (num == div)
                {
                    exit = true;
                    cout<<num<<endl;
                    sum += num;
                    cont++;
                }

                if (rest == 0)
                    exit = true;

                div++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"Sum: "<<sum<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I removed the last num++ and it works.
I'm italian, resto is equal to rest (in english). Before post this question I changed all the names of the variables, just because anyone that doesn't know italian could understand my code, but I forgot to change all the names.

Comment: I've just accepted it, and I modified my last comment.